# Add shapes in Listview - xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, drawing

I am using Xamarin.Form having android and ios project, I want to create add shapes in listview.

[image]

I search for same, we can use path class but dont know how to use it.

Please send me your solutions

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is path class you can use it.
Path class have a data property. for example

```
<Path Data="M 10,100 L 100,100 100,50Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Aspect="Uniform"
  HorizontalOptions="Start" />
```

The Data string begins with the move command, indicated by M, which establishes an absolute start point for the path. L is the line command, which creates a straight line from the start point to the specified end point. Z is the close command, which creates a line that connects the current point to the starting point.

Please review link given below, path is added in listview:
https://xamarinuidesigns.blogspot.com/2021/12/listview-ui-design-2.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Composite geometries`.

```
 <Path StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Orange">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50" />
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="25"
                         RadiusY="25"
                         Center="50,25" />
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
```

Usage in Listview:

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding list}" RowHeight="60">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Path StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Orange">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50" />
                                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="25"
                         RadiusY="25"
                         Center="50,25" />
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

For more details of the Composite geometries, please check the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/geometries#composite-geometries

Answer (score 0):

```
<Path Data="M 10,100 L 100,100 100,50Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Aspect="Uniform"
  HorizontalOptions="Start" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path

please review this link and you have any question then you can ask me?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).